# VirtualBox doesn't see raw partitions

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

What I want to achieve is to set up virtual machine with VirtualBox. Host OS is Windows 7 Home Premium, guest will be (k)Ubuntu 12.04 on a raw partition.

The first problem is that when I issue following command:

```
VBoxManage.exe internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
```

I get following result:

```
Number  Type   StartCHS       EndCHS      Size (MiB)  Start (Sect)
1       0xee  0   /0  /1   1023/254/63        715404            1
```

I'm guessing that VirtualBox is unable to see my partitions.

If I use *diskpart* tool, then all partitions are listed correctly (**note** Polish language version of Windows):

```
DISKPART> select disk 0

Obecnie wybranym dyskiem jest dysk 0.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partycja ###   Typ               Rozmiar  Przesunięcie
  -------------  ----------------  -------  ------------
  Partycja 1    System             200 MB  1024 KB
  Partycja 2    Zarezerwowany      128 MB   201 MB
  Partycja 3    Podstawowy         139 GB   329 MB
  Partycja 5    Nieznany          4883 KB   140 GB
  Partycja 6    Podstawowy          50 GB   140 GB
  Partycja 7    Podstawowy         484 GB   190 GB
  Partycja 4    Odzyskiwanie        24 GB   674 GB
```

Additional note: my PC is using EFI to boot OS.

Basing on the results listed above, I believe that:

- I messed up with my partition table.
- Something is wrong with VirtualBox.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Why not try the GUI. It is easier to create VMs there. And btw, I believe Windows can't see partitions other than the one it is currently residing in unlike Linux.

Comment: Well, what I tried to do is to use raw partition. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting to use VirtualBox GUI. AFAIK it is impossible to create raw disk or partition using VirtualBox GUI. BTW. the problem with VirtualBox not seeing my partition table correctly was connected to the fact my disk _was_ using GPT partition table. After I totally messed up and finally reinstalled all stuff, my disk uses now good old MBR partition table. Now VirtualBox sees my partitions correctly.

Comment: you should then answer your own question for other people's sake

Comment: I would be more than happy to answer my question for the sake of the others, but I was unable to resolve the issue. I've ended reformatting my hard drive - currently I don't use EFI - I use old good MBR partition format.